# Excel - Scraping HTML Source Layout with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have some terribly designed HTML that I am trying to scrape the data from to be easily readable.

I can use `innerHTML` to get the information, but unfortunately it comes out as a wall of text.

And example of the source from the webpage when I "view source" (words changed for privacy) is:

```html
<td nowrap valign="top"><b>Logger Notes</b></td>
    <td valign="top">Hi,
Person needs a full breakdown Important information.
Would also would like confirmation in a letter about what kinds of assistance 
she is not eligible for if possible.
Would prefer sent to email.
Thanks&nbsp;</td>
```

However when I get the data it comes out as a wall of text like so:

```
Hi, Person needs a full breakdown Important information. Would also would like confirmation in a letter about what kinds of assistance  she is not eligible for if possible. Would prefer sent to email. Thanks
```

This is obviously much harder to read.

When I use `innerHTML` and look at the string, all the newlines characters are actually space characters, so I can't use `replace`.

I've searched and tried many different things, but I can't work out a way to display it so it's easy to read.

The webpage is on our work intranet, and has a log in (that multiple people using the spreadsheet will use - so I can't automate this)

Example of prefered output:

```
Hi,

Person needs a full breakdown Important information.

Would also would like confirmation in a letter about what kinds of assistance she is not eligible for if possible.

Would prefer sent to email.
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please provide an example of what you would like to see as the output (which you consider readable).

Comment: Edited to show preferred output

Comment: When viewing the source document in a browser, is the text displayed how you want the output?

Comment: Nope, its displayed as the wall of text.(as it has no <br> etc)

Comment: In the source of the html document, (like the first box i think?) is it formatted with new lines etc?

Comment: Source is exactly as it is displayed in the example, its on new lines, but has no linebreaks in the code

Comment: If this will happen frequently fix the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, add a line-break after each occurrence of a period?

for example, `replace` the `"."` with `"." & vbCrLf`

Comment: Thats what I'm reduced to doing (at the moment)

The only downside that is requires the person who is doing the initial information entry to use grammar. (risky at best :) )

Comment: You can try counting characters and inserting a linebreak every 20-30 or so (in addition to linebreak at periods)) Will not look like original text from website but may layout better @JemSmall